# cURL vs ab performance testing

Tags: apache

I am troubleshooting a speed problem with an application running on Apache + PHP + MariaDB.  To start with, I test a static HTML page using this bash script:

```
 for i in {1..1000}; do
      curl -s $url > /dev/null
 done
```

This takes 14 seconds:

```
$ time ./curltest.sh 

real    0m14.647s
user    0m4.238s
sys     0m4.234s
```

When I test with `ab -n 1000 $url` it completes in less than one second.  What's the difference in these two tools and what should I learn from this test?

Comment: what is the $url string ?

Comment: $url = http://192.168.1.141 so it's index.html

Comment: Maybe you need a slash at the end like `http:// 192.168.1.141/` instead of `http:// 192.168.1.141`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fair comparison would be:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do
      curl -s $url > /dev/null
done
```

vs

```
for i in {1..1000}; do
      ab -n 1 $url > /dev/null
done
```

Starting process 1000 times is a different thing and asking already running process to run 1000 operations is different thing. that's the main reason.